# How to make type in Photoshop match that on a scanned image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, scanning

I have scanned some text, and I need to add a name in matching type and style. I have tried, but it's not as jagged as the scan, and doesn't look the same.

How do I make the added type match the scanned text? Please see the image for a comparison of the scan and what I've added.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you need to break regularity of your letters to look more like printed raster. I worked with your current image, if you will have higher resolution, you will need to adjust effect settings accordingly.

1. Copy you letters in a new file
   [image]
2. Double the image size (it will add some blur, which is good)

[image]

3. Add effect. Filter -> Pixelate -> Crystallize. Use "5" for cell size.

[image]

Image with effect:

[image]

4. Copy and paste back to your original file. Decrease the size to your original:

[image]

Quite close to the printed letters you try to mimic.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Your suggestion is helpful. i also get another solution which is with clone tools. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can make the new text **perfectly match** the scanned text,
if you can **replace the scanned text** also.

It may or may not work for your use case, but I think it's the only way to really do what you ask, *"make the added type match the scanned text"*.